# Data e hora de modificação de arquivos para download de um site em wordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugin, download, sistema-de-arquivos

Preciso de ajuda, tenho um site em WordPress. esse site tem uma pagina de downlaod de arquivos, eu gostaria de saber se existe algum plugin ou alguma forma de exibir a data e hora de modificação daquele arquivo para download.

Comment: Exibir aonde? Quando baixado ou antes de baixar?

Comment: Antes de baixar, na propria pagina do site